# DataGridView row loop and cell data access

Tags: c#, loops, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` populated from a database, and I need to take each row and create an object out of it. I can't figure out how to do it.

`DataGridView Columns: Name Price ProductId Condition MemberId Description`

Code I have:

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in members_dg.rows)
{
    foreach(DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        // need to get info. This should show u what im looking for. 
        //string name = cell1.Text;
        //string price = cell2.Text;
        //etc
        //Member member = new Member(name, price, ...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in members_dg.rows)
{
  // need to get info. This should show u what im looking for. 
  string name = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();  // first column
  string price = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();  // second column
  //etc
  Member member = new Member(name, price, ...);
}
```

You don't have to iterate through every cell, just call the cell index for the row you are on.

Comment: Found this very helpful. When you're looking through data structures in VS, the actual syntax to use isn't immediately obvious, at least to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(cell.OwningColumn.IsDataBound)
{
    Member member = new Member();
    //switch statement or you can use reflection
    switch(cell.OwningColumn.DataPropertyName)
    {
        case "name":
             member.Name=cell.Value;//need cast
        ....
    }
}
```